# Using scrypt to encrypt data in a session variable

Tags: encryption, pgp, session-management

Let's say I want to store some data in the node's session, for example, like an authenticity token. Obviously I want to store it in an encrypted way if it's going in a cookie, then decrypt it on a server to compare.

What's an acceptable way of accomplishing this? I was thinking of simply generating a random password on server start and using something like `PGP` to do the translation.

Is this a viable solution?

Comment: If you're generating a strong random key, you don't need to stretch it. Stretching is mainly useful for making it expensive to dictionary/brute-force weak passwords. If you're genning a strong key in the first place, theres no benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PGP will make your session a heck of large. So dont use PGP. Assymmetric cryptography is not required since the sender of the encrypted information (who encrypts), and receiver of the encrypted information (who should be able to read it), is the very same entity (your server).

This mean, that if you want to encrypt something to store in a cookie, use a symmetric cipher like AES256 instead.

But the best thing to do is not to store the data at all in cookies, instead, store it on server, generate a sufficently secure and random "session ID", and tie the "session ID" to the data blob on server.
The "session ID" is then what is sent via the cookie. Since the session ID is effectively random, that does not have any particular meaning for anyone else than your server, then it don't need to be encrypted.

Also scrypt is an password derivation function, not an encryption function, and is effectively one-way.

To prevent someone from hogging Resources on server, you can timeout sessions after a short period, and also have a function that if a specific IP request a new session, all old sessions from this IP is deleted.